# How do I use Simple_format and truncate together?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm totally stumped on this one. I've been trying to use simple_format and truncate on the same text and just can't figure out how to make it work. None of the answers I've found resolve the issue either.

I can either get it to format, or truncate, but not both ...

Here is the code:

```
<p> <%= simple_format h(truncate(recap.body, length: 500, separator: ' ')) { link_to '(read more)', recap} %> </p>
```

This has been driving me crazy for hours!

Thanks in advance!